# Setting a function to return its resulting value as a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

My goal is to have the function `SRA_Accession` return it's values as a string `e.g "Value1,Value2,Value3"` the code so far is

```
def SRA_Accession():
SRA=1293518
while (SRA < 1293618):
  SRA=SRA+1
  print "SRA"+str(SRA)
  if False:
   break
```

Comment: If you are looking to return something in that function, you currently are not using the explicit `return` that is required to actually return something from your function call.

Comment: What you mean by `if False` ? it never goes through `if` section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the lack of tabs are making this not work and you need a return statement which returns everything.

```
def SRA_Accession():
  SRA=1293518
  my_list = []
  while (SRA < 1293618):
    SRA=SRA+1
    my_list.append("SRA"+str(SRA))
  return ','.join(my_list)
```

Judging by the way you are writing the statement I would say you were looking to use a yield statement which returns each SRA string all by itself.  This means you will need to add commas outside the function like so.

```
def SRA_Accession():
  SRA=1293518
  while (SRA < 1293618):
    SRA=SRA+1
    yield "SRA"+str(SRA)

value = ','.join(list(SRA_Accession()))
print(value)
```

Comment: BTW can be replaced with `','.join('SRA' + str(n) for n in range(1293518,1293618+1))`.

Comment: Thank you ! I misquote the e,g, spaces in between each value work well for me

Comment: What?  You didn't add 1293518+1 together to make it 2 chars shorter?  I mean c'mon.

Comment: or how about  ',SRA'.join(map(str, range(1293517, 1293619)))[8:]